# How to check if a key exists in mako dict?

Tags: python, mako

Say if I have the following:

```
mydict = {
   a: 'A'
}
```

How do I check if key `a` exists in the dictionary? Pseudocode below:

```
%if 'a' in mydict.keys()
  ${mydict['a']}
%endif
```

Comment: The whole point of ``mako`` is using Python syntax for templates. Your pseudocode will actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `in`:

```
from mako.template import Template
t = Template("""
% if key in d:
    key is in dictionary
% else:
    key is not in dictionary
% endif
""")


print t.render(key='a', d={'a': 'A'})  # prints "key is in dictionary"
```